# Spatial autocorrelation of non-homogeneous point data in irregularly shaped sample plots

Tags: spatial, autocorrelation

Let's assume we registered the position of all individuals of different plant species within 3 irregularly shaped sample plots that are very close the each other. As an example, I put 2 pictures with 2 different species below. Each grid corresponds to 100m, and each circle represents one plant (the size of the circles is not important for this question).

[image: Species 1]

[image: Species 2]

We want to analyse to what extent the occurrence of individuals depends on various ecological variables.

In a number of similar studies, the authors provided a quantitative measure of the degree of intraspecies global spatial autocorrelation for each species, usually Moran's I.

However, I'm not sure how we could do this in our case, because:

- A global analysis of spatial autocorrelation, such as Moran's I, assumes homogeneity within the study area, which is clearly not the case.
- The shape of the sample plots is quite irregular.
- Many species are completely absent in one of the 3 plots.

We could try and find clusters at a local level using local spatial autocorrelation, such as LISA. If I understood LISA correctly, we would have to separate our study area in different homogeneous sub-units, which seems somehow arbitrarily.

What Information about intraspecies spatial auto-correlation could we provide based on our data?

Would this even make sense, from a statistical point of view, or should we better just describe the pattern qualitatively?

By the way, we are using R for the analysis.

Edit: Maybe some additional information about our study would help to answer the question. So far, we used present-only species distribution modelling techniques (like MaxEnt). Results are generally satisfying, with good model performance and predictions that make sense from an ecological point of view.

However, some authors warn that spatial autocorrelation between occurrences could influence the model. Therefore, we would like to present a *simple* measure (if possible) of spatial autocorrelation to describe the data.

Edit2: Regarding the suggestion to use Ripley's K or L-function:

As far as I know, those functions assume that underlying point processes are spatially homogeneous (stationary), which wouldn't be correct in our case. K and L-functions for inhomogeneous point pattern have been developed in recent years, which take non-constant intensity at each site in the study area into account (see for example [here](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/spatstat/html/Kinhom.html) for an emulation in R).

However, for our analysis, we are not really interested in spatial correlation *after* accounting for different intensities, but rather if different intensities are spatially auto-correlated (I don't know if this makes completely sense).

Comment: This question looks fairly interesting; looking at the data within each parcel of land, and your interest only in the presence, it seems that you would be looking at some form of multivariate Poisson process.  This unfortunately isn't my area of expertise.  Before you jump down the spatial rabbit hole though, you might want to first just ignore the spatial component initially and see how your results hold through a contingency table using the number of occurrences.

Comment: The standard approach to this question is to use Ripley's K or (better) L function and develop confidence bands around it through simulating the distribution under the null hypothesis of no spatial correlation ("complete spatial randomness"). This comes out of the box in some commercial GIS software like ArcGIS and is available in the free software CrimeStat; emulating it in `R` would not be hard.

Comment: @whuber: I edited my question according to your suggestion (thanks btw!).

Comment: @JonathanLisic: Thanks for your suggestion. Contingency tables show indeed that position of trees is highly dependent on environmental variables. Probably it would be really better to stay far away from that spatial rabbit hole.